# How to insert ListBox items separately to different row into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, gridview, listbox

I have a `ListBox`  which contains 3 items.

I want to insert each one of those 3 items separately into separate rows in a `GridView`, in order to insert it into `MySQL`.

For this case I need to split the rows into 3.
How can I do that?

Comment: hi Eirenaios , can you help how to solve with this?Thanks if you could help!

Comment: hello ashley, what have you tried? please read the article [ask] in order to help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (replace your connection string and SQL statement accordingly):

```
Using cn = New MySQLConnection(connectionstring)
    cn.open
    For each item in listbox1.Items
        Using cmd = New MySQLCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1) Values (@Value)", cn)
            cmd.AddWithValue("@Value", item)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Next
End Using
```

Comment: you mix up an insert statement with an update statement... insert into tablename (field1,field2,..., fieldn) values (value1,value2,...,valuen)

Comment: Thanks @Florian - I've done this a million times so not sure what I was thinking right then!